# SQL: Storing Extended ASCII (128 to 255) in VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, extended-ascii

How do you store chars 128 to 255 in VARCHAR..?

SQL seems to change some of these to char(63) '?'. I'm not sure if it's something to do with collation? UTF-8? N'..'? I've tried COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, not sure if it supports extended ascii though..

Obviously works with NVARCHAR, but in theory this should work in VARCHAR too..?

Answer (score 4):

The character stored in varchar/char columns beyond the ASCII 0-127 character range is determined by the code page associated with the collation. Characters not specifically defined by the code page are ether mapped to a similar character or, when there is none, '?'.

You can list collations along with the associated code page with this query:

```
SELECT name, description, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') AS CodePage
FROM fn_helpcollations();
```

Comment: very helpful, found the issue. It's using codepage 1252 which is missing some extended characters 129, 141, 143, 144, 157

Comment: @DaveSumter, you can avoid the code issue by using nvarchar/nchar instead.

Comment: Thanks Dan, am using nvarchar already. Just trying to fit this into varchar in order cut my column size in half. Using this to store large amounts of ascii only data..

Answer (score 0):

Dan's answer got me on the write track.

VARCHAR definitely does store Extended ASCII, but it depends on the code page associated with the collation. I'm using Latin1_General_100_BIN which uses code page 1252.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

According to this code page the the following chars are undefined:

129, 141, 143, 144, 157

In reality it looks like SQL exclude most chars from 128 to 159. Easy solution was just to remove those characters.

Comment: Right, "Extended ASCII" doesn't mean enough to use the term. Characters are in character sets. A character set has a name. "Extended ASCII" doesn't name a character set. But, your problem is that you don't seem the know the character set of your source data and are trying to store it into a system the wasn't designed to store it.

Comment: Sorry Tom, disagree. Extended ASCII is a fairly well understood term by most: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: "Extended ASCII" rarely conveys enough information. It means: an _unspecified_ character set of 129 to 256 characters, with a 1-byte encoding, where the first 128 characters match, and are encoded the same as, ASCII. When dealing with text, it is crucial to know the character set and encoding. There is no text but encoded text. If you don't know the character set, it scarcely helps to know that it is one of the dozens of extended ASCII character sets—and how could you know that without knowing the specific character set? There is only one way to know: the writer tells you somehow.

Comment: In many type systems, you can't store binary data (arbitrary byte values and sequences) in text data types. This includes SQL's CHAR, VARCHAR, NCHAR, NVARCHAR, .NET's String and Char, Java's String, Character and char, ….

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm not storing text. I'm storing byte values 1 to 255. Why can't you store byte values in text data types..? Thanks

Comment: In general, data types are for operations, composition, and association. Text operations include case changes, sorting and searching. None of those can be done with knowing the character set as well as a locale or collation. In storage or other services where data is made available to clients, the schema is often discoverable. In such cases, the character set of text data is passed to the client.

Comment: Thanks Tom, appreciate the info. Sorry, you lost me, but I think I understand the idea... But, CHAR and VARCHAR can store byte values. I have this working in production..

Comment: And when I read your table schema it will tell me that field is for text and uses a certain character set and collation. Would that be accurate?