# Problem when storing extended ASCII values in SQL db

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, extended-ascii

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 .I am trying to save extended special characters (ASCII values from 128-256) in SQL db. The collation of column is SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS, and the collation of database is also same.when I am saving these extended special characters these all are saving differently. I have checked the code page 1252 and these special characters are defined in code page. I have checked the system code page  in cmd using mode cmd and its 1252. How can I save these extended special characters in  db.

Comment: Are you certain they're not being stored properly? It's more likely they're being changed before the INSERT or after the SELECT. Also there is no 256 in CP 1252.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Storing Extended ASCII (128 to 255) in VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344747/sql-storing-extended-ascii-128-to-255-in-varchar)

Comment: Which specific characters are coming out differently than they were stored? Characters not defined in the codepage won't work. (everything from 0-255 isn't valid)

Comment: According to code page 129,141,143,144,157 are not defined.I have checked the db every special characters from 128-255 are saving differently.